# How the line_length variable of fix_screeninfo is counted?

Tags: c, linux, framebuffer

In my fbtest application I simply draw random in the framebuffer. The code is everywhere, it is very simple framebuffer usage. But I had some problems using the framebuffer - everything looked as I mapped memory incorrectly. After some time I have found that the formula which is used **everywhere** (Android, linux tutorials, a lot of other places) gives wrong result of bytes count in the frame line:

```
struct fb_var_screeninfo vi;
struct fb_fix_screeninfo fi;

// ... initialize the variables by the ioctls...

unsigned row_bytes = vi.xres * vi.bits_in_pixel / 8;
```

The `row_bytes` in this formula gives incorrect result actually which led in my situtation to incorrect image: real size was **2944** vs **2880** (720 pixels * 4 bytes in my case). I have found that the correct size is written in the `fi.line_length` variable. The question is why are they different, why everyone writes this formula if it gives wrong result? I have also tried to find any documentation about this but had no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula `xres*bits_in_pixel/8` gives the **width** of a row in bytes. This is not always the same as the **stride** of the image (the offset from one row to the next) because there may be padding between rows.

Documentation is indeed sparse, and example code is often wrong because a lot of people don't have hardware that makes this a noticeable issue. You just got lucky encountering it directly, so you are more educated than the average fb user.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you also add information about the padding, where it comes from?

Comment: To find out why padding exists in your particular case, we'd have to dig in to your hardware and driver. I only know of it being used to round an unusual width up to a nicer number, but 2944 is less nice than 2880 so I can't explain it. The good thing is the `fb_fix_screeninfo` tells you what it is, so you don't have to know why.